# C++ Segmentation Fault user input in an array

Tags: c++

can somebody say me what im missing?

```
int main() {
char eingabe[100];
cin >> eingabe;
eingabe[strlen(eingabe)]='\0';
cout << eingabe << endl;
}
```

But i get this: Segmentation fault

:(

Comment: Remove this unnecessary line: `eingabe[strlen(eingabe)]='\0';`

Comment: Please just think about `eingabe[strlen(eingabe)]='\0'` for a minute.

Comment: What is your input string?

Comment: You know that by-definition of a null char terminated string, `s[strlen(s)]` is *already* `0`, right? How do you think `strlen()` managed to determine its return value? And to answer the question, `std::string` is what you're missing.

Comment: If your input is longer than 100 characters, you're going to overflow your buffer, corrupt your stack, and do Bad Things to your program.

Comment: Just use `std::string` and safe yourself the trouble. Your program will break if the input is more than 99 chars long.

Comment: @BaummitAugen and just as bad if the extraction outright fails and that buffer content remains indeterminate.

Comment: None of you understand - strlen() is magic and can always determine the length of anything - file/network buffers with or without nulls in the data or at the end, arrays passed into functions as pointers, ANYTHING!  :)

Comment: You are missing `std::string`.

Answer (score 5):

If `cin` contains a line longer then 99 characters, the `cin >>` operator writes beyond the `eingabe[]` buffer end. This is wrong and likely to generate the segfault.

You may want to use the [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) class, rather then a `char[]` buffer.

If you have some good reason to use a char[100] buffer, then 
`cin.getline(eingabe,100)` is what you need.